# is there something wrong with this input user code?

Tags: c++

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct customer
{
    char fname[11];        
};

void name(customer& name)
{
    bool check = false;
    do {
        cout << "Enter your first name : ";

        cin.getline(name.fname, 10);// goal is to exit once press enter

        if (name.fname == '\n') //This doesnt work. i also tried using cin.get, cin.ignore, cin.peek and it still doesnt work, i tried changing the '\n' to '\0' and 0 just to see.
        {
            cout << "Invalid Entry\n";
        }
        else
            check = true;
    } while (check != true);
}

int main()
{
    customer cr;
    name(cr);
    return 0;
}
```

I created this code just to finally figure out how to use `cin.getline()`, its a simple code where it takes a name.

The goal is to enter a name and exit the code when pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Note: `getline` eats and discards the newline character. You won't find a newline in the string `getline` provides.

Comment: Note: `getline` already ensures that there is room for the null terminator. [Here's some good documentation you can use to brush up on `getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline)

Comment: Well, if it's open season on finding things that are wrong, using a fixed length `char` array, instead of `std::string` that makes so many things easier -- I'd say that meets the "something wrong" requirement.

Comment: There is something wrong with all code.  On Stack Overflow, you should ask a specific question that has a specific answer.  Stack Overflow is not designed for discussions or tutoring.

Comment: There's something so wrong about this: `void name(customer& name)`.  In most coding styles and guidelines, variable and function names should differ in more than just case.

Answer (score 1):

you dont mean

```
if (name.fname == '\n')
```

you mean

```
if (name.fname[0] == '\n')
```

Comment: Except that condition will never happen, because `getline()` will not store the terminating `'\n'` into `fname` to begin with

Comment: @RemyLebeau - i was going to add that too, but i thought, lets at least get it to compile

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare a `char[]` array to a single `char`, which will not work.  Use a string comparison like `strcmp()` instead.  However, `cin.getline()` will not store the terminating `'\n'` into `fname` to begin with.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct customer
{
    char fname[11];
};

void name(customer& name)
{
    bool check = false;
    do {
        cout << "Enter your first name : ";

        if (!cin.getline(name.fname, 11))
            break;

        //if (name.fname[0] == '\0')
        if (strcmp(name.fname, "") == 0)
            cout << "Invalid Entry\n";
        else
            check = true;
    }
    while (!check);
}

int main()
{
    customer cr;
    name(cr);
    return 0;
}
```

That said, you really should be using `std::string` instead of `char[]`, eg:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct customer
{
    string fname;
};

void name(customer& name)
{
    bool check = false;
    do {
        cout << "Enter your first name : ";

        if (!getline(cin, name.fname))
            break;

        if (name.fname == "")
            cout << "Invalid Entry\n";
        else
            check = true;
    }
    while (!check);
}

int main()
{
    customer cr;
    name(cr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I re check my code and i removed then i tred '\0'. it finally worked!! I also tried playing with NULL, nullptr and i guess it wont take that. THANK YOU SO MUCH GUYS!!! Ill try with string, this time, im still trying to get familliarize with it,